# Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

Tags: java, jpa

Preciso pegar de uma tabela chamada histórico os três último meses e um ano anterior para cadastrar na tabela produto. O código é o seguinte:

```
for (int i = prod.getHistoricos().size(); i >= 0; i--) {

                if (i == prod.getHistoricos().size() - 1 || i == prod.getHistoricos().size() - 2
                            || i == prod.getHistoricos().size() - 3 || i == prod.getHistoricos().size() - 13) {
                        mesesDoProduto.add(prod.getHistoricos().get(i).getMesesHistoricos());
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mesesDoProduto.size(); i++) {


                    if (i == 0) {
                        prod.setPrimeiroMesAnterior(mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                        System.out.println("====Mes===== " + mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                        prod.setSegundoMesAnterior(mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                        System.out.println("====Mes===== " + mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                    }
                    if (i == 2) {
                        prod.setTerceiroMesAnterior(mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                        System.out.println("====Mes===== " + mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                    }
                    if (i == 3) {
                        prod.setAnoAnterior(mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                        System.out.println("====Mes===== " + mesesDoProduto.get(i));
                    }

                }
                Double alfa = BigDecimal.valueOf((fatorAmortecimentoExponencial(arrayComUltimosCincoMeses)))
                        .setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
                System.out.println("Alfa " + alfa);
                System.out.println("Melhor taxa: " + alfa + " - resultado: "
                        + Math.round(calculoPrevisao(alfa.doubleValue(), arrayComQuantidades)));
                Long previsao = Math.round(calculoPrevisao(alfa.doubleValue(), arrayComQuantidades));
                listaComCincoUltimosMeses.clear();
                listaComQuantidade.clear();
                mesesDoProduto.clear();
                prod.setEmpresa(empresaSelecionada);
                prod.setGerenteFilial(gerenteFilial);
                prod.setFatorAmortecimentoExponencial(alfa);
                prod.setQuantidadeRecente(previsao);
                prod.setQuantidadeReais(prod.getValor().multiply(new BigDecimal(previsao)));
                cadastroProdutoService.importar(prod, gerenteFilial);// persistir
                                                                        // após
                                                                        // calcular
```

Na saída dos outputs tenho o seguinte :

====Mes===== Wed Jul 21 18:35:16 BRT 1999
====Mes===== Mon Jun 21 18:35:16 BRT 1999
====Mes===== Fri May 21 18:35:16 BRT 1999
====Mes===== Tue Jul 21 18:35:16 BRT 1998

porém ao salvar ocorre o seguinte erro :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getDateFast(ResultSetRow.java:131)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getDateFast(ByteArrayRow.java:243)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2003)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:1966)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2022)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getDate(NewProxyResultSet.java:2988)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DateTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DateTypeDescriptor.java:75)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
... 122 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
essa exceção ocorre porque você está ao que parece, tentando inserir uma data com zeros. E não existe uma data com zeros, por isso o erro.

Faça o seguinte, na sua url adicione a propriedade *zeroDateTimeBehavior*. Ela deve evitar a exceção.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Comment: na verdade não deveria estar inserindo com zero pois possui valor.

Comment: Mas alguém está tentando inserir com zeros. Talvez o Hibernate ou o Driver do MySQL ou o C3P0. O caso é, se usar a propriedade que te passei, vai resolver isso. Confira também no seu banco de dados se não tem lá alguma coluna de datas com zeros, porque na consulta elas podem resultar em exceção. Se existir, troque para null.

Comment: existiam colunas com zeros . ao tira la funcionou